# How to add Gmail annotation automatically in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, textinput, android-textinputlayout

I have created Login form with two TextInputLayout fields for email and password. In first TextInputLayout for email, I want to add Gmail annotation (@gmail.com) automatically like below.


[Wanted Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGMIk.png)

I think it is best in terms of UX point of view, if user email is abc@gmail.com then he only needs to enter abc and @gmail.com automatically shown.

Comment: I guess it is another layer of text view on top of the TextInputLayout. Like, put TextInputLayout in a frame layout and add the text view on the right

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.